# NetBeans deploy PHP application

Tags: php, visual-studio, netbeans

I come from a .NET visual studio background and am learning PHP (with CakePHP) using NetBeans.

In visual studio there is a publish option that allows you to publish your application via file system tranfer (essentially just spits out the application in the form that is needed for it to run on a webserver). Is there anything similar in netbeans?

I do all my dev work on the built in PHP webserver, and would like this file system transfer option so I can just copy and paste the files wherever I want  to.

I can't just copy the files from my working directory as it contains all the version control meta-data.

I am aware of the FTP and the remote server upload option, but I was hoping for the simpler approach as above.

Maybe the "visual studio approach" as above is not suited for a PHP environment, in that case I could use some pointers/tips!

Answer (score 0):

Heres how to deploy to a remote server using NetBeans https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html